# How to get permission of Facebook manage_pages on iOS develop?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to get access token of the page, so I followed the documents on Facebook. I'd like to ask for the permission when user login, here is my code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
    // Optional: Place the button in the center of your view.
    loginButton.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:loginButton];
    loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends", @"user_birthday"];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I just made a login button, and it will ask for the permission when user login,
after that, I can get public_file, email, user_friends, user_birthday.

But I also want to ask for the permission of manage_pages when user login so that I can have an access token of pages, what should I do next?

Comment: well....add it to your list of permissions?

Comment: I've tried, but not that simple.....

Answer (score 0):

I got it, just add:

```
loginButton.publishPermissions = @[@"manage_pages"];
```

and now it will ask for permission when user login.